# Unable to open iOS Words application to edit docx file in OneDrive from my own iOS mobile application via Office URL Scheme

Tags: ios, ms-word, ms-office, url-scheme, onedrive

I tried to follow tutorial on this document https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn911482.aspx to open .docx file stored on OneDrive to open and edit on Word App on iOS via URL Scheme.

How I did was create an url conform to what documented on the tutorial, associated with a shareable link get from OneDrive.

The actual url is: ms-word:ofe%7Cu%7Chttps://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=E943A3D72A4C8116!114&authkey=!ADZIc9QIedwfT6M&ithint=file%2cdocx

with ms-word is url scheme, ofe is "open for edit" as follow on the tutorial, and https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=E943A3D72A4C8116!114&authkey=!ADZIc9QIedwfT6M&ithint=file%2cdocx is the shareable link get from OneDrive

When open by [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:the_url_created_from_above], the app already open Word app, but get an error Cannot connect to URL, please use a valid URL

Could anyone let me know how to get correct or accessible url from OneDrive to work with iOS Word app via url scheme?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: well, on looking at the tutorial it seems to me that you're not formatting the URL correctly. I'm not seeing the pipes around the u in what you post. The instructions also say it needs to be a valid URL and not a redirect, but what you're showing as a "redir?" in it? "The URL has to be encoded and must be a direct link to the file (not a redirect). "

Comment: Thank you for getting back. because of url encoding, the pipes around the u already encoded to %7Cu%7C. The problem is I couldn't be able to get direct link to the file on OneDrive. If I change from redir to download, I could get the downloaded file directly without redirect but when I use that link, I still unable to open it on Word. Still say Invalid URL

Comment: Did you find a solution for this @BoySocola ?